# jQuery checkbox checked attribute

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$('#Liste_EMPL input:checkbox').attr ('disabled', false);
$('#Liste_EMPL input:checkbox:checked').attr ('disabled', true);
```

It **is** very clumsy, as it requires two lines of code whereas I mean:

«Set `disabled` attribute to `false` for all checkboxes that are NOT checked.»

It should be something like this:

```
$("#Liste_EMPL input:checkbox [checked='false']").attr ('disabled', false);
```

I have tried many syntactic forms to no avail.

What is the correct syntax? (Please no loop including conditional statements).

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not`

```
$("#Liste_EMPL input:checkbox:not(:checked)").attr('disabled', false);
```

Comment: — that IS final. Thank you.